# Passing C# function pointers into C++/CLI interop dll

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to pass a function pointer from C# into C++/CLI and getting a windows compiler error stating that the `ManagedTakeCallback` function is not supported by this language (C#)--I define the `ManagedTakeCallback` in the C++/CLI interop. My code looks like

C# application:

```
namespace ManagedConsoleApplication

{

class Callback
    {
        public delegate double DelegateAdd(double value1, double value2);

        public static double CallbackAdd(double value1, double value2)
        {
            return value1 + value2;
        }

        public static DelegateAdd delegateCallback = new DelegateAdd(Callback.CallbackAdd); //declare as static to prevent GC

    }

    class Program
    {
       // [DllImport("InteropDLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
       // public static extern void ManagedCallback(IntPtr pCallback);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InteropDLL io = new InteropDLL(); 
            Console.WriteLine("The Add return = {0}", io.ManagedAdd(3, 2));
            Console.WriteLine("Pass CallBack to Unmanaged code");
            Callback cb = new Callback();
            IntPtr intptr_delegate = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(Callback.delegateCallback); //convert delegate to function pointer which can be used by unmanaged code
            Console.WriteLine("The callback return is {0}", io.ManagedTakeCallback(intptr_delegate)); 
            Console.WriteLine("Please hit Enter to exit");
            String value = Console.In.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine("End of program ", value);
        }
    }
}
```

and,

C++/CLI interop dll h and cpp file:

```
//HEADER

namespace Interop
{

typedef double (__stdcall *PCallback)(double value1, double value2);

    public ref class InteropDLL
    {
    public:
        double ManagedAdd(double value1, double value2);

    public:
        double ManagedTakeCallback(PCallback pCallback);
    };
}

//CPP

double Interop::InteropDLL::ManagedAdd(double value1, double value2)
{
    return NativeAdd(value1, value2);
}

double Interop::InteropDLL::ManagedTakeCallback(PCallback pCallback)
{
    return NativeTakeCallback();
}
```

The C++/CLI interop layer then calls a C DLL. I'm able to call `ManagedAdd` interop function; however, if `ManagedTakeCallback` is added, there is a windows compiler error. I suspect that the C# application is not marshaling in the function pointer correctly via `ManagedTakeCallback` function or that the signature is not correct on the C++/CLI side? I would greatly appreciate any insight.

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a delegate to C++/CLI?

Comment: Wow, where do you get this windows compiler? :)

Comment: The windows compiler error is:

Comment: Sorry, forgot to past the error message: Program.cs(36,61): error CS0570: 'ManagedTakeCallback' is not supported by the language

Comment: You are trying to pass IntPtr when a native function pointer is expected.  Pretty unclear what you are trying to do but to get this code anywhere running you'll have to declare the ManagedTakeCallback() argument as IntPtr and cast to PCallback with (PCallback)(void*)pCallback.  Passing a delegate is the better approach.

Comment: SLaks, I converted the delegate to IntPtr so it could be handle by unmanaged code since the function pointer will ultimately be passed to a native C dll. This may not be necessary when it is passed to the C++/CLI layer?

Comment: Okay Hans, thank you, it now compiles. However, you suggest passing a delegate into C++/CLI. If so, what is the signature of ManagedTakeCallback and how would the delegate be converted to a function pointer which could then be passed to native C code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is comment from on site:

"But C# doesn’t suport C++ function pointer, so we cannot invoke a C++ function pointer here. C# only has Delegate objects and we have to convert the function pointer to Delegate by Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer. It is declared in System.Runtime.InteropServices as follows:

```
public static Delegate GetDelegateForFunctionPointer (
      IntPtr ptr,
      Type t)
```

for full answer look at link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27298/Dynamic-Invoke-C-DLL-function-in-C